# PyQt5 Table row height

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

Having read some similar posts here, I am still struggling to create a table using PyQt5 and Python 3.8 where I can control the row height.
[image]

The above image was captured from the code that follows. The rows are widely spaced, so I can display much less information than analogous tables like tkinter's Treeview.  The row size defaults to 25 pixels and I cannot find a way to shrink it.

The usual resizeRowsToContents and setRowHeight don't seem to do anything.  How do I fix this?

Here is the routine that adds each row:

## loads one row of the role table

```
def loadTable(self, row, names):
    row = self.castTable.rowCount()
    riter = iter(names)
    self.castTable.insertRow(row)
    #self.castTable.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(8)

    self.castTable.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(next(riter)))
    self.castTable.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(next(riter)))
    self.castTable.setItem(row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(next(riter)))
    #self.castTable.setRowHeight(row, 20)
    self.castTable.resizeRowsToContents()
```

And here is the main code that creates the table:

```
def build(self):
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)    #set up window
    self.setWindowTitle('Cast list')
    grid = QGridLayout()                    # and layout
    # create an empty 3-column table, no grid lines or vertical header
    self.castTable = QTableWidget(0, 3, self)
    self.castTable.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    self.castTable.setShowGrid(False)
  # table headers
    grid.addWidget(self.castTable, 0, 0, 5, 1)
    columns = ["Frname", "Lname", "Role"]
    self.castTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(columns)
    # self.castTable.horizontalHeader().font()
    # column widths

    self.castTable.setColumnWidth(0, 100)
    self.castTable.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
    self.castTable.setColumnWidth(2, 175)

    # add 3 rows
    names = ["Edwin", "Rodridguez", "Marco"]
    self.loadTable(0, names)
    names = ["Mike", "Costantino", "Guiseppe"]
    self.loadTable(1, names)
    names = ["John", "Matilaine", "Don Alhambra"]
    self.loadTable(2, names)

    # set the layout and show the table
    self.setLayout(grid)
    self.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setGeometry(700, 200, 500, 500)    #set up window
        self.setWindowTitle('Cast list')
        grid = QGridLayout()                    # and layout
        # create an empty 3-column table, no grid lines or vertical header
        self.castTable = QTableWidget(0, 3, self)
#        self.castTable.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)                   #
        self.castTable.setShowGrid(False)
        # table headers
        grid.addWidget(self.castTable, 0, 0, 5, 1)
        columns = ["Frname", "Lname", "Role"]
        self.castTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(columns)
        # self.castTable.horizontalHeader().font()
        # column widths

        self.castTable.setColumnWidth(0, 100)
        self.castTable.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
        self.castTable.setColumnWidth(2, 175)

        # add 3 rows
        names = ["Edwin", "Rodridguez", "Marco"]
        self.loadTable(0, names)
        names = ["Mike", "Costantino", "Guiseppe"]
        self.loadTable(1, names)
        names = ["John", "Matilaine", "Don Alhambra"]
        self.loadTable(2, names)

        # set the layout and show the table
        self.setLayout(grid) 
        
        for row in range(self.castTable.rowCount()):                        # 
            print(f'row={row}, rowHeight={self.castTable.rowHeight(row)}')  # 
        
    def loadTable(self, row, names):
        row = self.castTable.rowCount()
        riter = iter(names)
        self.castTable.insertRow(row)
        #self.castTable.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(8)

        self.castTable.setItem(row, 0, QTableWidgetItem(next(riter)))
        self.castTable.setItem(row, 1, QTableWidgetItem(next(riter)))
        self.castTable.setItem(row, 2, QTableWidgetItem(next(riter)))
        
        print(f'row = {(row+2) * 8}')                                        # 
        self.castTable.setRowHeight(row, (row+2) * 8)                        # +++
#        setRowHeight
#        self.castTable.resizeRowsToContents()                               # ---
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')                                                   # +++
    Form = MainWindow() 
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that did it. It seems that setStyle('Fusion')  was critical along with the setRowHeight statement.  Thank you!

Comment: @James  If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I just discovered that you can use the QTreeView and achieve the same spacing without all these manipulations. Thanks